# svn-ssh under ubuntu

Tags: ssh, svn

I use putty+pageant on Windows to be able to access the svn server by using ssh. I have my private key that works.

I'm now trying to use the same key on a Ubuntu VM.

I used the .p12 key in Firefox and it works well.

The problem is I can't use svn. I tried to follow the istructions that I found in several places on internet but it did not work.

The problem is that I don't know whether I did everything correctly.

I'm using a .p12 file format for the private key.

I renamed the key as `identity` and I copied it in the .ssh folder for my account. I also changed the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file uncommenting the line:

> IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity

I used the command:

> svn co svn+ssh://myusername@path_to_rep

The result is still

> svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly

I removed the -q option in the [tunnel] section of the subversion config file and now this is what I can see:

```
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openssh uses a different key format from putty.  You would need to use `puttygen` to convert/export your putty key into a format that openssh can use.

> 1. Open PuttyGen
> 2. Click Load
> 3. Load your private key
> 4. Go to Conversions->Export OpenSSH and export your private key
> 5. Copy your private key to ~/.ssh/id_dsa (or id_rsa).
> 6. Create the RFC 4716 version of the public key using ssh-keygen
>
>    ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa > ~/.ssh/id_dsa_com.pub
> 7. Convert the RFC 4716 version of the public key to the OpenSSH format:
>
>    ssh-keygen -i -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa_com.pub > ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
> 8. Fix the permissions of the private keyfile:
>
>    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa

Taken from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use

Comment: I tried to save the private key by using puttyGen but the created file is the same as the original one. I tried to save an SSH and a DSA file. In both cases the result is the same.

Comment: Anyway I followed the procedure and it did not work

Comment: It worked. I add to run ssh-add

Comment: you should also change the permission on the file: sudo chmod 600 keyfile

Comment: @herschel, sudo is not necessary when you already own the file.

Comment: sure you don't need it